# Issue with the service function -Angular

Tags: angular, service, components

task.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
   private tasklist= [{taskname:"sample task",taskdetail:"This is a test task",status:"todo"}];

  constructor() { }

  getTasklist(chosenstatus){
    return this.tasklist.filter((e)=>{

        if(e.status==chosenstatus){

          return e;

        }
    });

  }

  addTask(name,task){
    console.log(this.tasklist);/*this shows new task added*/
    this.tasklist.push({taskname:name,taskdetail:task,status:"todo"});
  }

}
```

Above is my service. After I add a task using addTask function, it adds the new task object into the task array but does not show while listing.

create-new.component.ts - to add new

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../task.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-new',
  templateUrl: './create-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-new.component.css']
})
export class CreateNewComponent implements OnInit {
  taskservice;
  constructor(taskservice :TaskService) {
    this.taskservice= taskservice;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form){

    this.taskservice.addTask(form.value.cardheading,form.value.cardcontent);
  }

}
```

task.component.ts - to show list

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() sts;
  todoService;
  taskService;
  constructor(toDoS:TaskService) { 
    this.taskService=toDoS;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoService=this.taskService.getTasklist(this.sts);
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the flow you invoke those two methods?

Comment: @haifzhan I have added some more info.above. I am creating a new task using ngSubmit of a form. Showing of the task is independent function as show above in task.component.ts

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you get tasks from `taskService` and then assign results to `todoService` variable and display it in HTML? And after pushing new task, there are no changes in HTML?

Comment: Yes @CommercialSuicide

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `todoService` in component doesn't update real-time because you just call this operation ones on component init and finally you have simple variable without binding to `tasklist` variable from service.

Your case is a perfect time for [Rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) and [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html). This way you can `subscribe` to changes and get new value after it was updated. Here is simple abstract example of what you want:

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9edvqf?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Here I modify service variable from one component, and it affects the variable in another component real-time. All magic goes here:

[image]

All you need is just to call `setVariableHolder` method to set new value:

```
this._abstractService.setVariableHolder('valueGoesHere'); // Replace 'valueGoesHere' string with any data you need
```

and `getVariableHolder` to get the updated value:

```
this._abstractService.getVariableHolder().subscribe(val => {
  this.anyComponentVariable = val;
})
```